# Nx "skipRemotes" don't works, Host still try to load

Tags: angular, host, nx-monorepo

I'm working on *"nx": "16.5.0"* and for project reasons need one Angular Host load an Angular Mfe from anoter monorepo, if I do the build and serve that with *Live Server* it works correctly but if I try to do a normal serve option I get an **Error**:

```
 >  NX   Invalid dynamic remotes configured in (...)"\host-angular\src\assets\module-federation.manifest.json": http-mfe-angular
```

Code of my Host *project.json*

```
"serve": {
      "executor": "@nx/angular:module-federation-dev-server",
      "options": {
        "port": 4200,
        "publicHost": "http://localhost:4200",
        "skipRemotes": ["http-mfe-angular"],
        "open": true
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "host-angular:build:production"
        },
        "development": {
          "browserTarget": "host-angular:build:development"
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "development"
    },
```

What I want is to prevent Nx from looking for the external Mfe and trying to load it, so that I can start the *serve* option correctly.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a bug in version 16.5.0 and earlier. The new versions have already fixed it.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).